# On Careers 2.0, to manage a job listing from several logins?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, user-accounts

Question basically sums it up. I'm using Careers 2.0 for some hiring. Am wondering if I can somehow share the listing (and not just profiles it turns up) with my colleagues, so they can access through their own logins?

Strikes me as a pretty reasonable feature request, if it doesn't currently exist, and I can't find it if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're working on this, but it's still a little ways away. In the meantime, you could create a new account with a log in you wouldn't mind sharing, and email careers@stackoverflow.com once done so we can merge it into your existing account. This will give people using the shared log in access to the listings and candidates in your account.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad to hear you're working on this feature -- doesn't create any big headaches for me at this point, but definitely would be a good feature to have.